# python 3.X concatenate zipped csv files to one non-zipped csv file

Tags: python-3.x, csv

here is my python 3 code:

```
import zipfile
import os
import time
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import re
import glob
import pandas as pd


# local variabless
# pc version
# the_dir = r'c:\ImpExpData'
# linux version
the_dir = '/home/ralph/Documents/lulumcusb/ImpExpData/Exports/92-95'


def main():
    """
    this is the function that controls the processing
    """
    start_time = timer()
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(the_dir):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".zip"):
                print("working dir is ...", the_dir)
                zipPath = os.path.join(root, file)
                z = zipfile.ZipFile(zipPath, "r")
                for filename in z.namelist():
                    if filename.endswith(".csv"):
                        # print filename
                        if re.match(r'^Trade-Geo.*\.csv$', filename):
                            pass  #  do somethin with geo file
                        # print " Geo data:  " , filename
                        elif re.match(r'^Trade-Metadata.*\.csv$', filename):
                            pass  # do something with metadata file
                        # print "Metadata:    ", filename
                        else:
                            try:
                                with zipfile.ZipFile(zipPath) as z:
                                    with z.open(filename) as f:
                                        # print("send to test def...", filename)
                                        # print(zipPath)
                                        with zipfile.ZipFile(zipPath) as z:
                                            with z.open(filename) as f:
                                                frame = pd.DataFrame()
                                                # EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file -- how to deal with this error
                                                train_df = read_csv(f, index_col=None, header=0, skiprows=1, encoding="cp1252")
                                                # train_df = pd.read_csv(f, header=0, skiprows=1, delimiter=",", encoding="cp1252")
                                                list_ = []
                                                list_.append(train_df)
                                                # print(list_)
                                                frame = pd.concat(list_, ignore_index=True)
                                                frame.to_csv('/home/ralph/Documents/lulumcusb/ImpExpData/Exports/concat_test.csv', encoding='cp1252')   # works
                            except:  # catches EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
                                print("EmptyDataError...." ,filename, "...", zipPath)

#    GetSubDirList(the_dir)
    end_time = timer()
    print("Elapsed time was %g seconds" % (end_time - start_time))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

it mostly works -- only it does not concatenate all zipped csv files into one. there is one empty file and all csv files have the same field structure with all csv files varing in number of rows.

here is what spyder reports when i run it:

```
runfile('/home/ralph/Documents/lulumcusb/Sep15_cocncatCSV.py', wdir='/home/ralph/Documents/lulumcusb')

working dir is ... /home/ralph/Documents/lulumcusb/ImpExpData/Exports/92-95

EmptyDataError.... Trade-Exports-Chp-77.csv ... /home/ralph/Documents/lulumcusb/ImpExpData/Exports/92-95/Trade-Exports-Yr1992-1995.zip

/home/ralph/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py:688: DtypeWarning: Columns (1) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
  execfile(filename, namespace)

Elapsed time was 104.857 seconds
```

the final csvfile is the last zipped csv file processed; the csv file changes in size as it processes the files

there are 99 csv files in the zipped file that i wish to concat into one non-zipped csv file

the field or column  names are:
colmNames = ["hs_code", "uom", "country", "state", "prov", "value",          "quatity", "year", "month"]

the csvfiles are labled: chp01.csv, cht02.csv, etc to chp99.csv with the "uom" (unit of measure) being either empty, or an integer or a string depending on the hs_code

Question: how do I get the zipped csv files to get concatenated into one large(estimated 100 mb uncompressed) csv file?

added details:
i am trying not to unzip the csv files, i would then have to go an delete them. I need to concat files because i have additional processing to do. The extracting of the zipped csv files is a viable option, i was hoping not having to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any reason you don't want to do this with your shell?

Assuming the order in which you concatenate is irrelevant:

```
cd "/home/ralph/Documents/lulumcusb/ImpExpData/Exports/92-95"
unzip "Trade-Exports-Yr1992-1995.zip" -d unzipped && cd unzipped
for f in Trade-Exports-Chp*.csv; do tail --lines=+2 "$f" >> concat.csv; done
```

This removes the first line (column names) from each csv file before appending to `concat.csv`.

If you just did:

```
tail --lines=+2 "Trade-Exports-Chp*.csv" > concat.csv
```

You'd end up with:

```
==> Trade-Exports-Chp-1.csv <==
...

==> Trade-Exports-Chp-10.csv <==
...

==> Trade-Exports-Chp-2.csv <==
...

etc.
```

If you care about the order, change `Trade-Exports-Chp-1.csv .. Trade-Exports-Chp-9.csv` to `Trade-Exports-Chp-01.csv .. Trade-Exports-Chp-09.csv`.

Although it's doable in Python I don't think it's the right tool for the job in this case.

---

If you want to do the job in place without actually extracting the zip file:

```
for i in {1..99}; do
  unzip -p "Trade-Exports-Yr1992-1995.zip" "Trade-Exports-Chp$i.csv" | tail --lines=+2 >> concat.csv
done
```

Comment: ok, i got the supplied shell script to work; If i wanted to do the same in python, how do i do so? other stackoverflow items suggest the pandas concat followed by pandas to_csv route works but it does not for me. Is there something i missed?